# Inline way to disable clang-tidy checks

Tags: c++, clang++, clang-tidy

I'm trying to set up clang-tidy for a project. I'd like to be able to have clean output, and encourage the use of -fix mode where possible. However, there are individual cases where an exception is needed.

Much as it is possible to use

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wreserved-id-macro"
// Code that is being specially exempted
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

for the equivalent case where one wants to locally disable a compiler warning, is it possible to do something similar from clang-tidy?

I have tried

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "readability-identifier-naming"
// Code that is being specially exempted
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

and also with `clang` replaced with `clang-tidy`. Unfortunately when using `clang` as the pragma target and compiling with regular clang, I get the compilation warning

```
warning: pragma diagnostic expected option name (e.g. "-Wundef") [-Wunknown-pragmas]
```

and

```
warning: unknown pragma ignored [clang-diagnostic-unknown-pragmas]
```

when compiling if I use `clang-tidy` in place of `clang`. Neither make an impact on what `clang-tidy` itself outputs when run over the source.

This is with `clang` and `clang-tidy` 3.8 on x86_64 Linux.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

Just add a comment containing the string NOLINT anywhere on the line you want clang-tidy to ignore. For example:

```
badcode;  // NOLINT

// NOLINTNEXTLINE
badcode;

// NOLINTBEGIN
badcode;
badcode;
// NOLINTEND

badcode; // NOLINT(cert-err-58-cpp)
```

See the documentation [here](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/#suppressing-undesired-diagnostics).

Comment: And indeed, it seems that opting out of specific checks by (putting-them, in-parentheses) after the // NOLINT is now a feature that was added some time around December 2017.

Comment: To provide an example for @RichL's good hint: `badcode; // NOLINT(cert-err58-cpp)`. This will disable only "cert-err58-cpp" warning and only for this single line (e.g. "cert-err111-cpp" could still be thrown). Make sure there is no white space between NOLINT and (.

Answer (score 18):

And since [LLVM 14.0.0](https://releases.llvm.org/14.0.0/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/index.html#suppressing-undesired-diagnostics), you can also use:

```
// NOLINTBEGIN(cert-err58-cpp)
multiple lines of code;
// NOLINTEND(cert-err58-cpp)
```