# C++ Warning: Assigning newly created gsl::owner<> to non-owner

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines

When I use the following code, I get a warning (From applying cppcoreguideline).
Code:

```
 SampleClass *object = nullptr;
 object = new SampleClass();
```

Warning:

```
 warning: assigning newly created 'gsl::owner<>' to non-owner 'SampleClass *' [cppcoreguidelines-owning-memory]
```

When I searched and get to this link
https://releases.llvm.org/8.0.1/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-owning-memory.html

which I am not able to understand,
Could someone kindly explain this in simple terms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`gsl::owner<T*>` is meant to designate that whoever holds this object is the *owner* of the underlying `T` object and is responsible for freeing the memory later. Note that an explicit delete operation is still required — the GSL annotation is meant to assist static analysis tools. (For more on ownership, see [this post](http://ericlavesson.blogspot.com/2013/03/c-ownership-semantics.html).)

When you assign a gsl::owner to a **raw pointer** such as `SampleClass *object`, the ownership semantics are lost and the static analyzer (clang-tidy in this case) is unable to verify that `object` is used correctly in the future. That's why you get a warning in this case: because it's a bad idea to lose this information and will often lead to incorrect code.

To fix this error you can annotate objects manually by using gsl::owner explicitly, for instance `gsl::owner<SampleClass*> object;`.

Another, possibly simpler alternative would be to use [`std::unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) (usually via `std::make_unique<SampleClass>()`) which will provide strong safety guarantees at compile time (even without the use of another analyzer like clang-tidy) as long as it's used properly. It will also **automatically delete the object**, which gsl::owner does not.

Comment: But what if you *actually want* a non-owing pointer? Something like `SampleClass* object = new SampleClass();` without triggering the warning? (I use wxWidgets, which deletes the object for me.)

Comment: @midrare We need to look into disabling undesirable clang-tidy checks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37950439/inline-way-to-disable-clang-tidy-checks