# clang-tidy does not recognize unifying assignment operator as move assigment

Tags: c++, c++11, clang-tidy

In my code I'm using an **unifying assignment** operator like this:

```cpp
MyClass& operator=(MyClass other) noexcept
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

but **clang-tidy** detect it only as copy assignment: in a class where I have implemented default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor and this unifying assignment, it detect the warning [cppcoreguidelines-special-member-functions](https://releases.llvm.org/17.0.1/tools/clang/tools/extra/docs/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines/special-member-functions.html#cppcoreguidelines-special-member-functions) with the following message:

> class 'MyClass' defines a non-default destructor, a copy constructor, a copy assignment operator and a move constructor but does not define a move assignment operator

Am I doing something wrong or is clang-tidy simply not able to identify him?
In the second case is it possible to solve this problem somehow?

Comment: the move assignment operator always has the form of `T& operator=(T&&)`

Comment: @NathanOliver I know, but defined this way it works with both l-values and r-values, so it works as both copy assignment and move assignment, and therefore I don’t expect to see that warning

Comment: It can work as a move assignment operator but it is suboptimal in terms of performance.  You are doing two moves when you do an assignment, the rvalue into the parameter and then `swap(*this, other)` will move again.  A move assignment operator in the form of `T& operator=(T&&)` will only do one move.

Comment: @NathanOliver In my case when the parameter is an r-value it is not moved, but the copy elision is used. Reference: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-and-swap

Comment: If it is a prvalue yes, that first one will be elided.  If you do `foo = std::move(lvalue_obj)` then you get two moves.

Comment: @NathanOliver Right, I hadn’t considered that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that your `operator=` is a copy assignment operator.

> A user-declared copy assignment operator `X​::​operator=` is a non-static non-template member function of class `X` with exactly one non-object parameter of type `X`, `X&`, `const X&`, `volatile X&`, or `const volatile X&`.

- [[class.copy.assign] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.assign#1)

Strictly speaking, there is no such thing as a "unifying assignment operator" and a move assignment operator needs to take an rvalue reference.

That being said, clang-tidy is not acting in the spirit of the core guideline when it issues this diagnostic. It should have a special case for this by-value copy assignment operator.

You could open an issue in the **[llvm/llvm-project repository](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project)** and request that clang-tidy handles this idiom specially.
Here is a [reproducible version of your problem](https://godbolt.org/z/7e6Yforso) that may assist you.

**Update:** I have submitted an issue: https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/76064

#### Workaround A

Personally, I find the by-value `operator=` idiom to be overrated.
It would be an ABI break if you ever wanted to split it up, and implementing two operators is not much effort:

```cpp
MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& other)
{
#if YOU_CARE_ABOUT_SELF_ASSIGNMENT_BEING_EXPENSIVE
    if (this != &other)
#endif
    {
        auto copy = other;
        swap(*this, copy);
    }
    return *this;
}

MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other) noexcept
{
    swap(*this, other);
    other.clear(); // very important to prevent hogging resources too long
    return *this;
}
```

Yes, you have to copy and paste a few additional lines this way, but it's more maintainable and won't trigger clang-tidy.

#### Workaround B

Disable the check just for your class.
This involves putting `// NOLINT` comments or pairs of `// NOLINTBEGIN` / `// NOLINTEND` comments in the right place.

See [Inline way to disable clang-tidy checks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37950439/5740428)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I agree with you that duplicating those few lines is not a problem. I opted for the unified implementation in order to define the copy assignment `noexcept`. What do you think about that?

Comment: @mparati yeah, being able to slap `noexcept` onto the assignment operator is convenient. To be fair, depending on how much is templated or configurable, you need conditional `noexcept` based on `std::is_nothrow_swappable`. The separate copy assignment operator also needs `std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible`. It's not that much effort either way.