# Lifetime issue instance of class || How to build my copy constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, instance, copy-constructor

My problem lies in the creation of instances of a class in my project.
This is how I create my instances and try to store them:

```
    for (const auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator(path))
    {
        auto x = path + "/" + std::filesystem::path(entry).filename().string();
        auto y = x.c_str();
        Texture text(y);
        inGameTextures.push_back(text);
    }
```

The goal is to load all images as textures from a specific directory and store all of them in a list.

I found out that this is not working, the first loaded images always being overwritten by the later ones.
That and the fact that the textures are not showing on screen at all must have to do with the lifetime of the instances, as I am creating all instances from a function.
I found out that I might need a copy constructor for my class, so I tried to add a basic copy and move constructor to my header:

```
    Texture(const char* path);
    Texture(const Texture& other) :
    texture(other.texture){};
    Texture& operator=(const Texture & that)
    {texture = that.texture;};
    Texture(Texture &&) noexcept = default;
    Texture& operator=(Texture &&) noexcept = default;
    ~Texture();
```

Of course this is not working either, but I can't really get behind the setup of copy cunstructors and what exactly I need it to copy for it to work correctly.
I was hoping someone could give me a hint what's wrong with these copy/move constructors and how to build mine correctly, and for any hints what else is wrong with my code, since none of it is really working.

For you to explore what I tried to do in my 'Texture' class, here is my header:

```
class Texture {
    private:
        unsigned int texture = 0;
    public:
        Texture(const char* path);
        Texture(const Texture& other) :
        texture(other.texture){};
        Texture& operator=(const Texture & that)
        {texture = that.texture;};
        Texture(Texture &&) noexcept = default;
        Texture& operator=(Texture &&) noexcept = default;
        ~Texture();

        int LoadImage(const char* path);
        void CustomizeTexture();

        struct data
        {
            std::string name;
            std::string documentExtension;
            glm::vec3 position;
            int ID;
        };

        static data& GetTextureData();
        static void SetData(const char* path);
        void SetID(int ID);
        static float RandomPositionValue();

        //int GetWidth() const { return width; };
        //int GetHeight() const { return height; };
    };
```

And here is what my .cpp essentially does:

```
Texture::data textureData;

Texture::Texture(const char* path) :
texture(0)
{
    textureData.ID = LoadImage(path);
    SetData(path);
}
```

Sorry for newbie mistakes, hope someone can help me anyways :)
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Usually a texture class wouldn't be copyable, only movable.

Comment: yes of course, it's a std::list<Texture> inGameTextures;
declared in the header file :)

Comment: oh, so I'd just need a move constructor? 
but the question still remains, I don't really know how to build that based on my code :(

Comment: You have one global textureData object. How do you expect loading many textures should work?

Comment: I thought by creating more instances of the class, each would have their own textureData, is that not the case? 
And how could I fix that? by creating the textureData in the constructor or maybe adding it to the copy constructor?

Comment: Each instance would have its own `textureData` if `Texture::data textureData;` was inside of the class, but it isn't (and if it was, you could omit the `Texture::` part).

Comment: So declaring the textureData as a member in the header file could fix the whole thing or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Not the whole thing, but it would be a good start. You also need a move constructor and a move assignment. The move assignment can (almost always) be implemented using the [copy&swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3279616/2752075). The copy constructor and assignment can and should be removed.

Comment: Why would you expect each instance of the class to have its own textureData?

Comment: If you do not use any C-style pointers, you probably don't need to write any of the big five (see "the rule of zero"). You may want to only delete copy ctor and copy assignment to prevent inadvertent copying.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thanks for the hint, I'll give this a read and try it out! super thankful for any starting points :)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I am really just a beginner in this and sometimes do not know how things I code turn out and why, so this is just me trying to understand :) 
I thought following the "rule of five" would not do any harm, but apparently I did to much, so I'll try to remove the copy constructor and assignment!

Comment: What is the ID returned by `LoadImage`?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it's an int as a return value of 'LoadImage', after loading the texture using the stb_image.h and generating the texture using `glGenTextures(1, &texture);`
texture is then the int value that's returned by the function!

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI So OP does need the rule of 3/5 to manage that texture handle.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes but none of the 5 should be custom, everything should be defaulted or deleted.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat and the rule of 3/5 is about the move constructor, not the copy constructor, just like you said, right?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI No, you need to manage the handle. The destructor needs to call `glDeleteTextures()` on that int, the move operations need to make sure two objects don't own the same handle, etc.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you are right

Comment: @notfynnaf The meaning of "3" and "5" became rather vague, I'm using it as a catch-all term meaning you need at least *some* custom copy/move operations (in this case only custom move operations). This is opposed to "the rule of 0", which means not having any custom copy/move operations whatsoever.

Comment: @notfynnaf The basic problem here is that the texure id is not copyable. It is a reference to an object allocated by the OpenGL library. Of course you can copy the integer but all you are really doing is copying the reference, so you end up with two references to the same underlying object and no way to know when to delete that object. You have two choices, make your texture class movable but not copyable, or use reference counting (i.e. `std::shared_ptr`).

Answer (score 2):

As commenters have already pointed out, the way your manage resources for `Texture` is broken. You are providing a copy constructor and destructor manually, but the move operations remain defaulted, which is pointless, since the defaulted move operations can bypass your usual manual management.

Since the texture ID returned by `glGenTextures` isn't copyable anyway (there exists no `glCopyTexture`), modeling unique ownership makes more sense:

```cpp
// note: prefer GLuint over unsigned int.
//       GLuint is a 32-bit unsigned integer so the closest thing would be
//       std::uint32_t, wheras unsigned int can be 16 bits or any greater width.
GLuint texture;

Texture(Texture &&other) noexcept
  : texture(std::exchange(other.texture, 0))
{}

Texture& operator=(Texture &&other) noexcept {
    reset();
    texture = std::exchange(other.texture, 0);
    return *this;
}

~Texture() {
    reset();
}

void reset() noexcept {
    // I'm 50% sure that you cannot delete the zero object, so let's check
    if (texture != 0) {
        glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);
        texture = 0;
    }
}

// optional, these are implicitly deleted
Texture(Texture const&) = delete;
Texture& operator=(Texture const&) = delete;
```

Unfortunately, we cannot delegate the work to `std::unique_ptr` because `GLuint` is not a *NullablePointer*.

Other than the resource management issues, it's hard to say what could be wrong. Maybe it's this, or maybe it isn't. You haven't provided a minimal reproducible example.

#### Note on copy-and-swap

Instead of a move assignment operator, you could also write a by-value copy assignment operator:

```cpp
friend void swap(Texture& a, Texture& b) noexcept {
    std::swap(a.texture, b.texture);
}

Texture& operator=(Texture other) noexcept {
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

See also: [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3279543/5740428)

Comment: Your move assignment is broken, you leak the old handle. I suggest taking the parameter by value and doing a swap instead.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm fairly sure I've fixed it now. Creating such an assignment operator would be an option too, but I'm not a huge fan of that idiom: it may come with performance downsides, it may result in clang-tidy false positives, it makes code less maintanable since having separate operators is an ABI break, and it overall doesn't bring *that* much to the table to make up for it.

Comment: Fair enough. Can you tell more about clang-tidy false positives?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat See [clang-tidy does not recognize unifying assignment operator as move assigment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77692186). I've opened an LLVM issue about this and there's a chance it will be fixed in the future, but right now it's a bit annoying.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `std::vector` instead of `std::list`, or use `emplace_back()` instead of `push_back()`?

It would be better if you have some sort of `TextureAllocator` utility which takes in a parameter - in your case path, constructs the object on heap, and returns a pointer or a smart-pointer. You can then track all sorts of reference metrics each time you transfer the pointer.